# A day or festival dedicated to a town or city

Tags: word-choice

Is there such a thing as a day (festival or celebration) dedicated to a town or city in Great Britain or the USA? What would such an event be called? 
For instance, I live in Mtsensk, Russia. Each year on a certain date there's a celebration dedicated to Mtsensk, as there are for other towns and cities in Russia. Each town/city has its own holiday once a year. 
Can I call it, in my case, Mtsensk Day? Is there such a term as a "town/city day" in general? Is there New York Day? Is there London Day? I've never heard of such celebrations in Great Britain or the USA.

Comment: The closest thing we Americans have are national holidays, like the 4th of July and New Year's... I don't know of any cities that celebrate their own personal festivals. I live in New York City, and we don't have any city-wide celebrations that commemorate the city itself. At least, as far as I know.

Comment: In New York, we have various festivals, like the Tribeca Film Festival or the Mostly Mozart Festival (which is taking place now until Aug. 12th). But nothing that celebrates the city itself.

Comment: If you have to write about a Russian town in English, simply translate день города literally. If you are writing about an American or British (or German or French) town, you don't need to write anything at all as that just isn't a thing that exists there.

Comment: Ok, then would Mtsensk Day or Mtsensk festival go for such event in your opinion?

Comment: It should be clear from context what town you mean. So just go with Day of the Town. (After all, it's not called "день города Мценска" in Russian, either. That sounds really funny. It's just "день города", period.) I still have my backstage pass for a день города in Moscow, where I danced for the Russian president clad in medieval armour (I mean, I was clad in it, not him), and it's always rather hard to explain to people why anyone would ever do such a thing or what's written on the card. Usually I just go with Day of the Town. But City Festival doesn't sound bad either, I might steal that.

Comment: FWIW, wiki doesn't even have an English article on the thingie. They have one in Ukrainian and one in Esperanto, of all things, where apparently it's *urbofesto* or *tago de la urbo* (so once again, literally "day of the town" is the best people could make up in a language that is all made up and anything goes).

Comment: Well, actually we can say "День города Мценска", it doesn't sound funny at all, it is a normal phrase and, additionally, it is used in local papers, on the Internet and on TV.

Comment: "day of the town" doesn't sound good in my opinion. If there's Independance Day or Labour Day then Mtsensk Day will go too. And if I am asked what Mtsensk is, I'll specify. I think that if there were such a thing in London or New York, the name of the day would be London Day or New York Day respectively, for sure.

Comment: It's called whatever it's called.  Our little burg in southern Minnesota has "Good Neighbor Days".  The metropolis just east of us has "Rochesterfest".

Comment: Yeah, fwiw, **do *not* call it "Day of the Town"** as a name. It serves as an awkward gloss, but would be "Town Day", "X Day", "the X Festival" as a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in context "Mtsensk Day" would be both clear and natural. It's not a concept I'm aware of in any English-speaking town, but we do have [Yorkshire Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yorkshire_Day) for the county.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in English-speaking areas are American **[county fairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agricultural_show)**, British **[county shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_shows_in_the_United_Kingdom)**, and (patron-)**[saint's days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_of_saints)**. Municipal festivals as such are less of a done thing, although some cities have favorites—e.g. New York's St Patrick's Day & Halloween blow-outs—and Canada apparently has a [bizarre generic 'civic holiday'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civic_Holiday) on the first Monday in August. It's all on the same day across the country, but some municipalities rename it for their own observances, calling it (e.g.) "John Galt Day" in Guelph, Ontario.

You could gloss the Russian idea as "a local" or "town festival" but using the word "fair" runs the risk of confusing it with traditional regional markets and "show" obviously usually implies that there's just one longish performance. You're probably best off going with **Mtsensk Day** and spending a sentence, parenthetical, or footnote explaining the Russian practice.